# LaTeX with no embedded Fonts

Tags: fonts, conversion

I have a simple question, I would like to produce some latex document which has all its fonts rendered in vector graphic form, no embedded fonts, is this possible and how can I achieve this by using the standard latex build chain?

Do I need to use `dvi2ps` or `ps2pdf`? And what are the properties to set there?

Comment: What do you mean by `vector graphics form`? That will require the fonts anyways. Are you having problems with bitmapped fonts?

Comment: @daleif: He wants to convert glyphs to vector paths which would be then included just as any other vector images. A font would then be required only at compile time, not at rendering time.

Comment: If you are doing this in order to prevent text copying, better do not. It will still be possible to OCR the document, while it will prevent normal users from using text search and will drop any hinting or other special font information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the following `ghostscript` call to your processing chain:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pswrite -sOutputFile=- -q -dNOPAUSE With-Fonts.pdf
   -c quit | ps2pdf - > No-Fonts.pdf
```

**EDIT:** This doesn't quite work, however. (it produces bitmap fonts (pixel stuff)):

But the following command does seem to to work:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pswrite -sOutputFile=- -q -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE With-Fonts.pdf
   -c quit | ps2pdf - > No-Fonts.pdf
```

credit goes to: [Remove embedded fonts from a pdf](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1666/remove-embedded-fonts-from-a-pdf).

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for fixing my answer :-)

Comment: newer versions of gs seem to not have `pswrite`, only `ps2write`. Unfortunately it doesn't do the expected anymore.